# Dns records, and tomcat on loadbalacing

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, tomcat, load-balancing, bind

I have 2 Dns servers (Debian) configured using bind9
and a loadbalancer managing 2 tomcat webservers,
My question is Should i put dns entries of the 2 tomcat webservers, or i just have to put the loadbalancer ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your load balancer is going to accept connections for your back end services and load balance them to the servers behind it. In this case, the connection should be made to the load balancer. The DNS should point the public name of the service to the IP of the load balancer.